# Has any Buddhist ever talked about postponing Buddhahood forever, but not for all sentient beings?

Tags: nirvana, compassion, buddha, bodhisattva, buddha-nature

Has any Buddhist ever talked about postponing Buddhahood **forever**, but *not* for all sentient beings?

I do not, I suppose, mean because the "bodhisattva" enjoys life. I am trying to ask about "[compassion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karu%E1%B9%87%C4%81)" for some group or even individual, if that is possible?

I don't mind if the answer ignores the alledged universality of Buddha-nature, but would prefer if it was from that perspective.

Comment: just curious, not about to try to actualize that!

Answer (score 1):

first karuna is not compassion. the pali word for compassion is anukampam.

second the buddha does not even claim he reached nibanna out of karuna, nor out of anukampam. The buddha claims that he taught out of anukampam though.

Answer (score 0):

"Yes", the [Buddha](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/ptf/buddha_en.html), since he thought of the best way for all in a non-naive way, compassionate (=wise) and naturally also didn't encourage anybody to such as "Bodhisattva-hood", as it is popular this days... for peoples livelihood and to justify their eating and harms.

If more interested in what the Buddha act-ually taught and what his way was, it's good if turning toward the "good teachings"

> "Even though I was endowed with such fortune, such total refinement, the thought occurred to me: 'When an untaught, run-of-the-mill person, himself subject to aging, not beyond aging, sees another who is aged, he is horrified, humiliated, & disgusted, oblivious to himself that he too is subject to aging, not beyond aging. If I — who am subject to aging, not beyond aging — were to be horrified, humiliated, & disgusted on seeing another person who is aged, that would not be fitting for me.' As I noticed this, the [typical] young person's intoxication with youth entirely dropped away. (equal with illness and death)...

You may not like it since it would take away all of your excuses that you do no efforts for a better where it would be possible. The Buddha and wise can "live" with this normality of beings.

*(Note that this is not given for trade, exchange, stacks and entertainment but to become [free of "Buddha-nature"](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/thanissaro/headandhearttogether/Section0016_en.html)... an exit)*